# Eclipse paho mqtt C++ as dependency in another project

Tags: c++, paho

I have not much clue how c and c++ works at compile and runtime!

We are trying to use Eclipse Paho C++ library as a dependency in the project and messed up right now.

We have reffered to https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/tree/master/src/samples and used the same code in our project but we get this error.

> error: 'mqtt' has not been declared class callback : public virtual mqtt::callback

We also have the following in place

1. Copied all the C and C++ libs(libmqttpp.so  libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0   libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1  libmqttpp.so.0       libpaho-mqtt3as.so      libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 libmqttpp.so.0.1     libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1    libpaho-mqtt3cs.solibpaho-mqtt3a.so    libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0  libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1
   libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1  libpaho-mqtt3c.so       libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0) to /usr/local/lib
2. Copied .h files(MQTTAsync.h  MQTTClient.h  MQTTClientPersistence.h) to /usr/local/include

Apart from above 2 steps, do I need to add anything to my project to resolve the problem or I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It worked after doing the following steps

1. Download 'C' zip from http://build.eclipse.org/technology/paho/
2. Copy lib files to /usr/lib/
3. Modified SConscript(alljoyn/gateway/gwagent/GatewatConnector/samples/) to extend LIBS - gwcnc_env.Prepend(LIBS = [**'paho-mqtt3a', 'paho-mqtt3c'**, 'alljoyn_about', 'alljoyn_services_common', 'alljoyn_notification', 'alljoyn_config', 'alljoyn_gwconnector'])